# Upgrading issue from angular4 to angular5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have done following steps

> 1) Upgraded angular CLI to 1.5 
>   2) Accordingly changed in package.json
>   and after following these step getting below mentioned error

---

```
 ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: [object Object]
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed: [object Object]
 @ multi ./src/polyfills.ts
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update from Angular 4 to Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47070229/how-to-update-from-angular-4-to-angular-5)

Comment: I think its might be just a new line error also may be reflect metadata issue. you add reflect-metada dependencies and see if it resoves

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried by upgrading reflect-metadata dependency version to 0.1.10 but still i am stuck with same error