# ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module ngx-swiper-wrapper found version 4, expected 3

Tags: javascript, angular, node-modules

I'm using swiper module which on installation runs fine but when I re serve the project then I'm stuck with error:
[The plugin link](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-swiper-wrapper)

> ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module
>   E:/xampp/htdocs/havemybooks/node_modules/ngx-swiper-wrapper/dist/ng
>   x-swiper-wrapper.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol
>   ComponentModule in E:/xampp/htdocs/havemybooks/src/
>   app/component/component.module.ts, resolving symbol ComponentModule in
>   E:/xampp/htdocs/havemybooks/src/app/component/com ponent.module.ts

Here is the result of my `ng -v`

```
@angular/cli: 1.4.2
node: 6.10.3
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.5
@angular/common: 4.4.5
@angular/compiler: 4.4.5
@angular/core: 4.4.5
@angular/forms: 4.4.5
@angular/http: 4.4.5
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.5
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.5
@angular/router: 4.4.5
@angular/cli: 1.4.2
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.5
@angular/language-service: 4.4.5
typescript: 2.3.4
```

Comment: Is it OK to downgrade ngx-swiper-wrapper version to 3?

Comment: Yes I can but I don't know what particular version is their version 3 their versioning is like 5.3.0 the one I've installed so Don't know what their version 3 is.Moreover I think the error is regarding angular version which is the only 4 I see (lol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After opening an issue I found that this error is due to the versioning problem as most of the plugins in the version 5 are not compatible with version 4.

Either Update your project from 4 to version 5 using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47070229/how-to-update-upgrade-from-angular-4-to-angular-5) it might be time-consuming as your projects might have dependencies that are v4 compatible only so I preferred not to do that.

I ended up installing an older version of the plugin using:

```
npm install ngx-swiper-wrapper@prev --save
```

Similarly installing an working old version can be installed using the `releases` part in `GitHub` or going through the doc as most plugins give references to older versions.

Similarly, for another plugin, I faced the issue which was solved using the same approach.[Consider this issue](https://github.com/amitmahida92/ng4-loading-spinner/issues/19)

**Update:** After a few months I would like to suggest upgrading your project itself. Just create a new blank project after upgrading to the latest angular version(6 as of now) and copy your `src` there and install each plugin separately by looking at your `package.json` this will install the latest versions of your plugins(Although there might be functionality change with new versions so don't forget to check them too). I know it feels hard first but I can assure you it won't cost you that much as much finding suitable versions for your old project.