# Errors upgrading from angular 2 to angular 5

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript, angular5

I am trying to upgrade an Angular 2 Visual Studio project to Angular 5. I had reasonably good luck with it compiling until I tried to upgrade angular/router to a compatible version. The original "3.0.0-rc.1" compiles but uses OpaqueTokens, so it doesn't work.

When I try to add the version for angular/router specified in the new package.json below all sorts of normal typsescript types such as Boolean then don't get recognized. It looks like the compiler is completely messed up. I don't know if I even need the @angular/upgrade for this version of the code.

I've tried to do some of the things mentioned on [How to update / upgrade from Angular 4 to Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47070229/how-to-update-upgrade-from-angular-4-to-angular-5) but none of the accepted solutions works for me.

The original angular 2 package.json was:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.3.0-rc.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.8.4",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.4",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.63",
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "browserify": "^14.1.0",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "compress": "^0.99.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.4.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.1.5",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "mangle": "^1.1.3",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "systemjs-builder": "^0.16.3",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10",
    "typings": "^0.7.12",
    "uglifyjs": "^2.4.10"
}
```

Current config is:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.10",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.11.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "systemjs": "0.21.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
    "@types/node": "^9.6.6",
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "browserify": "^16.2.0",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "compress": "^0.99.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.4.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.1.0",
    "karma": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "mangle": "^1.1.3",
    "protractor": "~5.3.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "systemjs-builder": "^0.16.3",
    "tslib": "1.9.0",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.5.0",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "uglifyjs": "^2.4.10"
}
```

someone asked about the build configuration in the package.json

this is the scripts in the package.json file. There is something wrong here even if this worked for angular 2, because when you do npm run build it complains about not knowing about "clean"

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "build": "npm run clean && tsc",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "posttest": "node_modules/.bin/remap-istanbul -i coverage/coverage-final.json -o coverage -t html",
    "coverage": "http-server -c-1 -o -p 9875 ./coverage"
}
```

The tsconfig.json file is below. I had to add the line "lib": ["dom"] to the file to prevent a compile error.

```
{
     "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "es5",
     "lib":  ["dom"], 
     "module": "system",
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "sourceMap": false, // make this false for minification
     "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
     "experimentalDecorators": true,
     "removeComments": false,
     "noImplicitAny": false,
     "noStrictGenericChecks": true,
     "outFile": "./app/app.min.js" // uncomment this line for minification
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "typings/main",
      "typings/main.d.ts",
      //comment out these two lines for jasmine
      "./app/**/*.spec.ts",
      "./app/*.spec.ts"
   ]
}
```

Comment: Why are you installing a specific version `@angular/router` (i.e. `"@angular/router": "5.2.10"`)? What version of the other Angular packages is getting installed?

Comment: It looks like the configuration may be correct, but I have to compile somehow using ng build rather than npm build. It compiled correctly when I did this manually at the command prompt. I'm still waiting on input from one of the other developers for unrelated issues but if this works I will post it as an answer.

Comment: What is in your `package.json` file for the `build` script?

Comment: I've added the script section of the package.json and the tsconfig.json to the question

Comment: I found a better way to do this upgrade, using npm itself. I also had to remove the deprecated typings and just use a few specific @types.

I also removed es6-shim and angular/uprgrade. I was wrong about needing to use ng build. 

I posted the question here, and it is answered.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069300/typings-seems-utterly-messed-up-after-converting-project-from-angular-2-to-angul?noredirect=1#comment87162501_50069300

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do the upgrade is to use npm install, as I did here:

[Typings seems utterly messed up after converting project from angular 2 to angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069300/typings-seems-utterly-messed-up-after-converting-project-from-angular-2-to-angul?noredirect=1#comment87162501_50069300)

There is an answer that I eventually found to the question. It turned out that I didn't need es6-shim and removing the deprecated typings and replacing them with specific @types worked.