# update angular from version 5 to 6

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have bit confused after updating angular5 to 6 because of the occuring below errors.

i have updated the rxjs version from 5.5 to 6.1.0 and also updated typescript version to 2.7.2.

i have followed the https://update.angular.io version update from 5.2 to 6.0 and rxjs version update guide https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

**here is the error occurred:**

```
yarn run v1.5.1
$ ng serve --open --proxy-config proxy.conf.js 
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "/home/aravinda/Desktop/example/ui".
Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "/home/aravinda/Desktop/example/ui".
    at Object.resolve (/home/aravinda/Desktop/example/ui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node/resolve.js:141:11)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable [as _subscribe] (/home/aravinda/Desktop/example/ui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/architect.js:132:40)
    at Observable.subscribe (/home/aravinda/Desktop/example/ui/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:162:69)
    at DoOperator.call (/home/aravinda/Desktop/example/ui/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/tap.js:71:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (/home/aravinda/Desktop/example/ui/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:159:22)
    at /home/aravinda/Desktop/example/ui/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeTo.js:22:31
    at Object.subscribeToResult (/home/aravinda/Desktop/example/ui/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeToResult.js:7:45)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (/home/aravinda/Desktop/example/ui/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:132:38)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (/home/aravinda/Desktop/example/ui/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:129:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (/home/aravinda/Desktop/example/ui/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:112:18)
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: sh
Arguments: -c ng serve --open --proxy-config proxy.conf.js
```

Comment: please install this package: `"rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0"`

Comment: if your problem is solved, please feedback me, thanks

Comment: You need to do `npm install --save @angular-devkit/build-angular`

Comment: try this update guide https://update.angular.io/

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the upgrade steps mentioned below

1. Make sue that your nodeJS version is 8.9+
2. Upgrade rxjs to 6.0.0-beta.0, please see  RxJS Upgrade Guide for more info. RxJS v6 has breaking change hence first make your code compatible to latest RxJS version.
3. remove node modles then npm install further  update npm cli globally

   ```
    npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
    npm cache verify
   ```

   if your version of npm is lessn than 5 you should do

   ```
    npm cache clean
    npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@next
    npm install
   ```
4. to update angular Angular framework packages to v6

   ```
    ng update @angular/core
   ```
5. update angular material

   ```
    ng update @angular/material
   ```
6. make typescript independent so that it doesn't need any dependency

   ```
    npm install -g rxjs-tslint
    rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json
   ```
7. change angular pacage version in package.json to  to ^6.0.0-rc.5

   ```
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.0-rc.12",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/material": "^6.0.0-rc.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
    "core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0-uncanny-rc.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-uncanny-rc.7",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
    },
   "devDependencies": {
   "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.5.0",
   "@angular/cli": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
   "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
   "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
   "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
   "codelyzer": "~4.1.0",
   "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
   "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
   "karma": "~1.4.1",
   "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
   "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
   "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
   "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
   "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.4",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2"
    }
   ```
8. Update angular cli configuration format

   ```
   ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4
   ```
9. in case if you get error on typescript

   ```
   npm install typescript@2.7.2
   ```
10. run ng serve to give try to  it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, add `rxjs-compat` package to project solve my problem.

please try this approach:

add this item `"rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0"` to `dependencies` section in `package.json` and run this command:

`npm install --save`

Comment: @Aravinda Rathnayake please test and feedback me, i hope this is helpful for you, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link to update to angular 6

[How to update / upgrade from Angular 4 to Angular 5+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47070229/how-to-update-upgrade-from-angular-4-to-angular-5/48363318#48363318)

Now open the boot.server.ts file from client app

and change the following line of code

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { enableProdMode, ApplicationRef, NgZone, ValueProvider } from '@angular/core';
import { platformDynamicServer, PlatformState, INITIAL_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { createServerRenderer, RenderResult } from 'aspnet-prerendering';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.server.module';

enableProdMode();

export default createServerRenderer(params => {
    const providers = [
        { provide: INITIAL_CONFIG, useValue: { document: '<app></app>', url: params.url } },
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: params.baseUrl },
        { provide: 'BASE_URL', useValue: params.origin + params.baseUrl },
    ];

    return platformDynamicServer(providers).bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(moduleRef => {
        const appRef: ApplicationRef = moduleRef.injector.get(ApplicationRef);
        const state = moduleRef.injector.get(PlatformState);
        const zone = moduleRef.injector.get(NgZone);

        return new Promise<RenderResult>((resolve, reject) => {
            zone.onError.subscribe((errorInfo: any) => reject(errorInfo));
            appRef.isStable.first(isStable => isStable).subscribe(() => {
                // Because 'onStable' fires before 'onError', we have to delay slightly before
                // completing the request in case there's an error to report
                setImmediate(() => {
                    resolve({
                        html: state.renderToString()
                    });
                    moduleRef.destroy();
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

to the below line of code

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { enableProdMode, ApplicationRef, NgZone, ValueProvider } from '@angular/core';
import { platformDynamicServer, PlatformState, INITIAL_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { createServerRenderer, RenderResult } from 'aspnet-prerendering';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.server.module';

enableProdMode();

export default createServerRenderer(params => {
    const providers = [
        { provide: INITIAL_CONFIG, useValue: { document: '<app></app>', url: params.url } },
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: params.baseUrl },
        { provide: 'BASE_URL', useValue: params.origin + params.baseUrl },
    ];

    return platformDynamicServer(providers).bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(moduleRef => {
        const appRef: ApplicationRef = moduleRef.injector.get(ApplicationRef);
        const state = moduleRef.injector.get(PlatformState);
        const zone: NgZone = moduleRef.injector.get(NgZone);

        return new Promise<RenderResult>((resolve, reject) => {
            zone.onError.subscribe((errorInfo: any) => reject(errorInfo));
            appRef.isStable.subscribe(() => {
                // Because 'onStable' fires before 'onError', we have to delay slightly before
                // completing the request in case there's an error to report
                setImmediate(() => {
                    resolve({
                        html: state.renderToString()
                    });
                    moduleRef.destroy();
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The app will run on Angular latest version

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instruction from this link [Angular 5.2 update to angular 6 visual studio mac 7.5.2 using Asp.net core 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50740499/angular-5-2-update-to-angular-6-visual-studio-mac-7-5-2-using-asp-net-core-2-1/50754060#50754060). This is the solution for visual studio 2017 and visual studio for mac