# Angular 5.2 update to angular 6 visual studio mac 7.5.2 using Asp.net core 2.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I am trying to update Angular 5.2 create from .netcore 2.1 core template using below command

```
dotnet new angular -o my-new-app
cd my-new-app
cd ClientApp
npm install --save <package_name>
```

Link used to create angular project - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

Now I followed the link to update to Angular 6 [How to update / upgrade from Angular 4 to Angular 5+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47070229/how-to-update-upgrade-from-angular-4-to-angular-5)

use the another link to update but all the link is showing me same errors
https://asish.com.au/how-to-upgrade-angular-5-application-to-angular-6-with-visual-studio-2017/

https://update.angular.io/

But getting lots of error like

**An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: Unknown option: '--extractCss'
))**

Here is my Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "WebApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --extract-css",
    "build": "ng build --extract-css",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build -- --app=ssr --output-hashing=media",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.4",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~10.3.1",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.1.0",
    "protractor": "^5.3.2",
    "ts-node": "~6.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.10.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.1"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0"
  }
}
```

**start.cs**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "WebApp": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "progress": true,
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "WebApp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "WebApp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "WebApp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "WebApp-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "WebApp:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "WebApp",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "css"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

Error details

[image: Error Details]

Can anyone please let me know how to convert angular 5.2 to angular 6 with proper link

Comment: Can you add your angular.json? Think you are missing a rule.

Comment: On mobile don't want to type it out, give this a try https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10666

Comment: No it didn't solve the issue

Comment: Odd that it didn't work, reason you are getting that is because ng serve doesn't support --extract-css anymore. Changing that config should of worked. Alternatively you can just remove --extract-css from your scripts for 'start'

Comment: Nope that also doesn't work